# logical expressions and implication

Tags: logic

I am given 3 statements and I have to determine whether they implicate each other or not. however the use of $\forall$ kind of confuses me. 
the statements are the following ( forgive me if i'm addressing them in the wrong way) :

1. $(\forall x \alpha(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x \beta(x)) $
2. $\forall x (\alpha(x) \rightarrow \beta(x))$
3. $\exists x \alpha(x) \land \lnot \exists x \beta(x) $

Comment: $\forall$ means the relation should hold for every $x$ in the domain. I think you need to tell what is $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and write down how you tried the problem.

Comment: That is it. I know what forall means, I just can't figure out if 1 implies 2 for example because of that \forall there..

Comment: $(\forall x \alpha(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x \beta(x))$ is the same as $(\exists x \neg \alpha(x)) \vee (\forall x \beta(x)) $.


$\forall x (\alpha(x) \rightarrow \beta(x))$ is the same as $\forall x (\neg \alpha(x) \vee \beta(x))$


$\exists x \alpha(x) \wedge \neg \exists x \beta(x)$ is the same as $\forall x \alpha(x) \wedge \forall x \neg \beta(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If 2. holds in some model, this means that for all $x$ in the model, if we know $\alpha(x)$ holds for that $x$ then we can conclude $\beta(x)$ holds for that $x$ as well.

So if we know or assume that for all $x$ in the model $\alpha(x)$ holds, so we
assume $\forall x \alpha(x)$, then applying 2. at each $x$ of the model, we also know that $\beta(x)$ holds for all $x$, so $\forall x \beta(x)$. So the implication
$$(\forall x \alpha(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x \beta(x))$$
is valid in that model.

Conclusion: 2 implies 1 in all models.

If we have a model for 3. then it cannot be a model for 1 anymore: for if all elements would satisfy $\alpha$ (and there is at least one, from satisfying 3.) then all elements would satisfy $\beta$ too, and this is also not the case when 3. is satisfied.

Conclusion: 3 implies not 1, or equivalent, 1 implies "not 3".